# Serving Electron renderer process over HTTP and using require

Tags: javascript, requirejs, electron

I'm trying to make a mobile version of my Electron app by serving the HTML and renderer javascript files over a HTTP server started from the main process.

My renderer process javascript makes heavy use of require's. They work fine inside Electron. Outside of Electron, they don't because `window.require` is not defined.

So I tried to rewrite a bit of code, so that it works with modules being either `required` or previously loaded in a `<script>` tag.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
// Initial situation:
const $ = require('jQuery');
// on mobile : require is not defined

// Try 1
if (window.require) {
  const $ = require('jQuery');
}
// doesn't work: $ is only defined in the scope of the if

// Try 2
let $;
if (window.require) {
  $ = require('jQuery');
}
// on mobile : $ was defined from jQuery being loaded from a script tag,
// but I just overwrote it with undefined

// Try 3
let $;
if (window.require) {
  $ = require('jQuery');
}
else {
  $ = window.$;
}
// on mobile : window.$ is undefined
```

Can anybody see what I'm missing? Or maybe just tell me how to set up `require` on a non-Electron page?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following:

```
if (window.require) {
  window.$ = require('jQuery');
}
```

and then using `window.$` instead of `$` throughout the renderer process.

Comment: `window.$` and `$` are considered the same in a browser environment.

Comment: if you open the devtools on this page, `windows.$$$` is undefined and `$$$` is a ReferenceError. So they're not exactly equivalent. In my case, window.$ doesn't exist beforehand so I have to explicitly set in on the window (or declare a local variable).

Comment: Oh right, the bundler will not consider them as the same